# Unity 3D Texture : Black border

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

When I create a texture, unity add a "black broder" to it.

How can I delete it ?

Please see this image to understand what is my issue :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/feqlhamsyibf3qr/mroizo.png

My inspector:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mz52wt8fbxyceyu/mroizo2.png

Thank you for your help.

Regards,

AB

Comment: Looks 2D to me, have you tried using a Sprite instead of a Texture? The issue looks like a blend mode issue, specifically if the image was created with the border pixels anti-aliased towards the alpha channel (transparency). If you don't need anti-aliased outline you might want to simply re-create the image without embedded anti-aliasing.

Comment: Show your circle texture